# Store a JSON in the PostgreSQL database of a Corda node

Tags: corda

I have a scenario where I need to store a large JSON String in the PostgreSQL database of a Corda node.
Does a Corda node support this type of scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically I think you can store a large string as part of a state in corda. However, it would perhaps not be a great idea to do so. The larger the string would be the bigger the transaction size would be and thus greater network latency. Also if the string becomes part of the state, it would get copied across its state evolution and hence any node not having previous transactions of the state would need to download the complete backchain which means all the previous consumed states which adds up the network latency.

It would rather be better to add a reference to the state like a hash of the json file.